# In Android, I need to read a txt file from my app but that txt file is not created by my app in "Scoped Storage" Is it possible?

Tags: android, file, android-ndk, readfile, scoped-storage

As we are having scoped storage now in Android, so I am trying to read a text file at the NDK level which is not owned by my app.

Basically, downloading this file from some other applications like Gmail, Outlook, etc., Since it will be in the download folder for opening the file, I am using the below code.

I have tried with open() and read() API but the value of "filereturn" is coming out to be -1 only.

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_example_testing2_MainActivity_ReadTxtFile (JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {

        int filereturn;
    filereturn = open ("/storage/emulated/0/Download/token.txt", O_RDONLY);
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Tag", "Open file:%d-->%d\n", filereturn,errno);
    
    if (filereturn != -1) {

        char buffer[100] ={};
        int count = read( filereturn,buffer, 99);
        __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Tag", "Success file:%d-->%s\n", count,buffer);
        close(filereturn);
    }

}
```

I thought we could read the file atleast, but if I am wrong please do correct me.

If we could achieve it, can you please tell the correct way of doing it?

Observed this in Android SDK Version:32

Help is appreciated.

Comment: If your app does not own that file, then you must ask the user to select it and give you access to it. There's no way around that part. Are you asking how to take a `Uri` you receive from that request and read the file at the NDK level?

Comment: No it's not about that @ianhanniballake

Comment: Okay, well there's only two parts to this process: asking the user to select a file to give your app access to (which there are plenty of questions about explaining it is not possible to do anything with `startActivityForResult` at the NDK layer) and how to read the file given the `Uri` you receive. Since your question isn't about the later part, as per your comment, should this question just be marked as a duplicate of a question that explains the first part? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: This is a runtime config file, which when read by the app, the behavior will change. So, I cannot start the app with this file. If its not possible in Downloads folder, what's the correct place?